# GridView Layout RowSpan Issue

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, gridview

i'm building an android app using Android Studio and I want to display my items(images-using imageViews) in rows(4 in each one) but when I add more than 4 items, instead of the next item been taken to the next row, it just doesn't show up at all. What am I missing? I tried tweaking multiple things but none of it worked. Keep in mind that i'm new to android app development so i'm not sure if my layout choices are "optimal".Below you will find my xml file that handles all of the layout parts:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
                android:text="Cards List"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:textSize="40sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:columnWidth="90dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:numColumns="4"
                    android:paddingBottom="500dp"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
                    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp">

                </GridView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA

```
package com.example.steli.hellogridview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"" + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

IMAGEADAPTER.JAVA

```
package com.example.steli.hellogridview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
```

/**
 * HelloGridView was
 * Created by Stelios Papamichail on 11/5/2017.
 *

* This file belongs to the com.example.steli.hellogridview package.
 */

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// Create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if(convertView == null) {
        // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180,180));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.ssj4_gogeta,
        R.drawable.cell_jr_n,
        R.drawable.mrsatan_n,
        R.drawable.tien,
        R.drawable.vegito,
        R.drawable.videl
};
}
```

Comment: Let's see your adapter and how you instantiated your `GridView`.

Comment: Sure, I updated my post! :D

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your Java code. Your XML, however, is pretty messed up.

Why, for example, do you cascade a `LinearLayout` inside a `LinearLayoutCompat` inside a `NestedScrollView`? For scrolling the `GridView`, you don't need **any** of this. So take it out.

Also, `android:paddingBottom="500dp"` is too much. This line pushes part of your `GridView` outside the top of the screen (at least on the emulator I use). So get rid of that, too (or make the padding smaller).

I don't understand what you want with the `AppBarLayout`, so I leave it untouched.

Since you probably don't want the `GridView` to render on top of it, I put the `AppBarLayout` and the `GridView` inside a `RelativeLayout` with `android:layout_below="@id/appbar"` inside the `GridView`'s XML.

So the XML now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
                    android:text="Cards List"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:verticalSpacing="10dp">

        </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```